# How to get an item from n implemented list in c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get an item from a list with this code in c#:

```
var app = _appsmetiers.SingleOrDefault(am => am.nomApplication == nomApplication);    
static List<AppMetierModel> _appsmetiers = new List<AppMetierModel>
            {
                new AppMetierModel {
                    nomApplication = "Microsoft Office 2013",
                    dateInstallation = DateTime.Parse("02-02-2014"),
                    nomDossierInstallation = "C:\\",
                    description = "..."
                },
                new AppMetierModel {
                    nomApplication = "Windows Seven Service Pack 1",
                    dateInstallation = DateTime.Parse("02-02-2014"),
                    nomDossierInstallation = "C:\\",
                    description = "..."
                },
                new AppMetierModel {
                    nomApplication = "Microsoft Office 2013",
                    dateInstallation = DateTime.Parse("02-02-2014"),
                    nomDossierInstallation = "C:\\",
                    description = "..."
                }
            };
```

But this wouldn't work, and threws this exception :

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Any suggestion, please ?

Comment: @GrantWinney, Thanks Grant for your comment. I've updated my post. :)

Comment: Try using SingleOrDefault-  Should throw exception if more than one item.

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't sure that line of code would throw that exception if `Single()` was the problem, but it's easy enough to replicate, and it does throw that exception:

```
var result = new List<int> { 1, 1 }.Single(x => x == 1);  // InvalidOperationException
```

You're either matching no elements in the list, or you're matching multiple elements.

If you're positive there could be *at most* one single match, use [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var l = _mylist.SingleOrDefault(am => am.username == username);
```

If there could be multiple matches, but you only want the first one, use [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var l = _mylist.FirstOrDefault(am => am.username == username);
```

---

After seeing your posted code, you've got two records where `nomApplication` equals "Microsoft Office 2013". If that's the string you're searching for, then that's why you're having issues.

`Single()` expects one match and one match only.

Comment: I've used string values, may this cause that exception ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using SingleOrDefault() instead of Single()

SingleOrDefault will work fine if there are no matching elements (0), or exactly 1 matching element. If it's 2 or more it will crash.

...Or you could throw an exception.

```
    try 
    {
        var l = _mylist.Single(am => am.username == username);
    }
    catch(InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Error", e);
    }
```

Comment: I've used string values, may this cause that exception ?

Comment: Nope, it means that the "username" is appearing being matched either twice or not at all on your list. The exception will happen regardless of type